# Native module resolution

Tags: javascript

If I import a module using the native syntax like so:

```
import React from 'react'
```

How does the JavaScript runtime know where to look for the file containing the "react" module, given that no absolute of relative path is specified?

Comment: imports are transpiled using babel where you can configure module resolution. By default, it looks in `node_modules`.

Comment: Thank you. So this is a feature of babel, and without babel, all module specifier strings will be absolute or relative paths?

Comment: No. Babel transpiles `import` statements to [require](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/). What you really want to know is how `require` works - look at those [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/modules.html#all_Together...).

Comment: If you turn these comments into an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel transpiles import statements to [require](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/).

These [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/modules.html#all_Together...) describe how `require` works.